# Response is always null when send request to BizTalk WCF Service

Tags: web-services, asmx, biztalk

1. i have created on orchestration with 2 ports. 1st is request-response two way port which is receiving request from my web service. 2nd is request-response two way port which is forwarding that request to another web service to retrieve data.
2. then i have deployed the project in biztalk administration.
3. project is published as wcf service in IIS
4. i have added the reference of wcf service to my asp.net project.

**Issue:** when i am sending request from my asp.net project to biztalk wcf service it is working fine. forwarding that request to the next service and reeving data from there.

**if i am writing data on disk in file in my port configuration its fine but in my response back to my request its always null.**

please help me to solve this issue.

```
string strRequest = "Here is my xml"

using (OrchestrationRTA2_Port_App2Client btsSvc = new OrchestrationRTA2_Port_App2Client())
{

var result = btsSvc.Operation_1( new RequestRoot

                    {
                        RequestPacket = strRequest
                    });
                    string str = "";
                    if (result != null)
                        str = result.ToString();

                    btsSvc.Close();
                }
```

Comment: How is the File Send Port connected to the Orchestration?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused if the `Receive Pipeline` on your BizTalk Two Way Receive port (the one created when you exposed your Orch as a WCF service) is set to Passthrough, instead of Xml. Can you check this?

HTH